# Yarn v2+ lockfile, how the validate new checksum

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Yarn v1 lockfiles contain an integrity checksum that can be validated against the checksum in the npm registry or yarn registry.

```
accepts@~1.1.0:
  version "1.1.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/accepts/-/accepts-1.1.4.tgz#d71c96f7d41d0feda2c38cd14e8a27c04158df4a"
  integrity sha512-8EKM6XlFgqSpDcxkT9yxCT8nDSWEVBD0UjgUWMCWh5kH9VU+ar2MhmDDYGxohXujPU8PPz88ukpkvfXFVWygHw==
  dependencies:
    mime-types "~2.0.4"
    negotiator "0.4.9"
```

`sha512-8EKM6XlFgqSpDcxkT9yxCT8nDSWEVBD0UjgUWMCWh5kH9VU+ar2MhmDDYGxohXujPU8PPz88ukpkvfXFVWyg` can then be simply compared to the checksum stored in the npm/yarn registry:

https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts/1.1.4

```
1.1.4": {
      "name": "accepts",
      "version": "1.1.4",
      "dist": {
          "integrity": "sha512-8EKM6XlFgqSpDcxkT9yxCT8nDSWEVBD0UjgUWMCWh5kH9VU+ar2MhmDDYGxohXujPU8PPz88ukpkvfXFVWygHw==",
      }
}
```

However in yarn v2+ lockfiles these checksums changed, and I cannot find any documentation on what this new checksum is nor on how to verify it against the one stored in the npm or yarn registry API. (https://registry.npmjs.org/) or (https://registry.yarnpkg.com/)

```
"accepts@npm:~1.1.0":
  version: 1.1.4
  resolution: "accepts@npm:1.1.4"
  dependencies:
    mime-types: ~2.0.4
    negotiator: 0.4.9
  checksum: 0c9d4ae055460b30f30606266cbb8700fcb4ad07cc7c2f16fb852cf541c31f32706c35178e89c27f8c05323d1f5764918a85197ae5d609ad556409bbf868c9f2
```

I want to know what kind of checksum this  is (0c9d4ae055460b30f30606266cbb8700fcb4ad07cc7c2f16fb852cf541c31f32706c35178e89c27f8c05323d1f5764918a85197ae5d609ad556409bbf868c9f2) and if its compatible, in terms of verifying the integrity, with the one stored in the npm/yarn registry as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the checksum by downloading the tgz and running the following command

```
 curl 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com/accepts/-/accepts-1.1.4.tgz#d71c96f7d41d0feda2c38cd14e8a27c04158df4a' | openssl dgst -sha512 -binary | openssl base64 -A
```

this gives you

```
8EKM6XlFgqSpDcxkT9yxCT8nDSWEVBD0UjgUWMCWh5kH9VU+ar2MhmDDYGxohXujPU8PPz88ukpkvfXFVWygHw==
```